# What is the right command line to call the collada file?

Tags: three.js, collada

I have this code but I don't know what the right command line to add the collada files. I have them with the source file I got from the programmer. The rest of the file is working and the camera position and everything else is right.

```
function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );



            scene = new THREE.Scene();


            // Add the COLLADA

            scene.add( dae );
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada

What this does is it uses a custom loader included like this:

```
<script src="js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js"></script>
```

And then it uses it to load the DAE and add to the scene asynchronously:

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.load( './models/collada/monster/monster.dae', function ( collada ) {
    dae = collada.scene;
    scene.add(dae);         
});
```

Comment: Do I need to a web server to run something like that? I mean does three.js generally need a web server?

Comment: Normally yes, you can't execute HTTP calls like downloading a file in most browsers by default when opening a local file (i.e. file:///...html). I'd suggest you install a simple webserver like WAMP (http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or if you have Pyton (http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python)